# How to force javac to use a certain jar file?

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, classpath

In my corporate machine, we have `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/opennlp-tools-1.5.3.jar` and in my application I actually want to use an older version, say in `$DIR/lib/opennlp-tools-1.3.0.jar`.

When I'm trying to compile using `javac -cp $DIR/lib/opennlp-tools-1.3.0.jar MainClass.java`, apparently `javac` still use `opennlp-tools-1.5.3.jar`, that is, the version in the `$JAVA_HOME` (I know this from the incompatibility produced, and that removing the opennlp tools in `$JAVA_HOME` makes it run smoothly)

#### Question

Is there a way to tell `javac` to use the jar file that I specified?

As I said above, removing the jar file in `$JAVA_HOME` works, but it might break other applications, so I want minimal changes to the file structure. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try and pass this option to javac (in addition to the -cp):

```
-Djava.ext.dirs=$DIR/lib
```

to avoid looking at the extensions in $JAVA_HOME. It seems that -cp does not override this.

Comment: That works! Thanks. Basically you can change `java.ext.dirs` to anything, and it won't look at `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext`, right?

Comment: A better idea would be to REMOVE the extensions.  They are a bad idea ... unless it is essential that all Java applications use those extensions.  (That is clearly not the case for you.)

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But I need to check with the dev team as in who are using those files.

Comment: If NLP is what I think it is, it is indeed a weird choice for a system-wide extension.